# How to manage stock availibility (in_stock or outof_stock) of product with Undo cancellation of order

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, inventory, order-status, stock

I am trying to develop undo cancelled order extension. For that I am extending  OrderController.php.

```
    class Extension_Undocancel_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function undocancelAction()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();

        try {
            foreach($items as $item) {
                $canceled = $item->getQtyCanceled();
                if($canceled>0) {
                    $productUpdates[$item->getProductId()] = array('qty' => $canceled);
                }
                $item->setData('qty_canceled',0);
            }
                Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->registerProductsSale($productUpdates);
                $items->save();

            $order->setBaseDiscountCanceled(0)
                ->setBaseShippingCanceled(0)
                ->setBaseSubtotalCanceled(0)
                ->setBaseTaxCanceled(0)
                ->setBaseTotalCanceled(0)
                ->setDiscountCanceled(0)
                ->setShippingCanceled(0)
                ->setSubtotalCanceled(0)
                ->setTaxCanceled(0)
                ->setTotalCanceled(0);

            $state = 'new';
            $status = 'processing';

            $order->setStatus($status)
                ->setState($state)
                ->save();

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Order was successfully uncancelled.'));
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Order was not uncancelled.'));
        }

        $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
    }

}
```

It works fine even update product stock as per canceled quantity but If product quantity become zero it still show in stock.

How I can update stock availability if qty becomes zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following updated code sort the problem mention above. I hope this will help someone.
(If you have modification  or error please comment)

```
class Extension_Undocancel_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{
public function undocancelAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
    $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
    try {
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $canceled = $item->getQtyCanceled();
            if($canceled>0) {

                $productUpdates[$item->getProductId()] = array('qty' => $canceled);
                $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($item->getProductId());

                    if (((int)$stockItem->getQty() - (int)$canceled) <= (int)$stockItem->getMinQty()) {
                        $stockItem->setIsInStock(false)
                            ->setStockStatusChangedAutomaticallyFlag(true);
                    }
                    $stockItem->save();
            }
            $item->setData('qty_canceled',0);
        }
            Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->registerProductsSale($productUpdates);
            $items->save();
        $order->setBaseDiscountCanceled(0)
            ->setBaseShippingCanceled(0)
            ->setBaseSubtotalCanceled(0)
            ->setBaseTaxCanceled(0)
            ->setBaseTotalCanceled(0)
            ->setDiscountCanceled(0)
            ->setShippingCanceled(0)
            ->setSubtotalCanceled(0)
            ->setTaxCanceled(0)
            ->setTotalCanceled(0);
        $state = 'processing';
        $status = 'processing';
        $order->setStatus($status)
            ->setState($state)
            ->save();
        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Order was successfully uncancelled.'));
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Order was not uncancelled.'));
    }

    $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
}
```

}